# Dynamically created tabs - destroy object when tab closed

Tags: python, memory-leaks, pyqt, pyqt5, qtabwidget

I am dynamically creating multiple tabs, and I was wondering if when I close the tab, does it actually destroy the object?

I have set the attribute of the dynamically created tab to QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose

I assume that setting the attribute doesn't do anything because the closeEvent isn't called on it.

```
    self.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.close_handler) # connect close button to slot

    def close_handler(self, index):
        'Remove added tab if applicable'
        try:
            #self.tabWidget.widget(index).deleteLater() #does this need to be added?
            self.tabWidget.removeTab(index)
        except:
            Data.logger.exception('Exception occured:')
```

How do I make sure that the object is being destroyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is oriented to explain details that the other answer does not indicate so that you understand how it handles the memory Qt.

If you want to know if a QObject is eliminated then you must use the [`destroyed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed) signal.

If you want to delete a QObject you must use the [deleteLater()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) method.

In the case of the elimination of a widget added to the QTabWidget this will notify the QTabBar that it will be deleted so there are no problems of accessing non-reserved memory.

Considering the above, a possible solution is:

```py
def close_handler(self, index):
    widget = self.tabWidget.widget(index)
    widget.deleteLater()
```

You can check it with the following example:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(tabsClosable=True)
        self.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.onTabCloseRequested)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabWidget)

        for i in range(10):
            widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            widget.destroyed.connect(
                lambda obj: print(
                    "deleted {}, count: {}".format(obj, self.tabWidget.count())
                )
            )
            self.tabWidget.addTab(widget, "Tab %s" % (i))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onTabCloseRequested(self, index):
        widget = self.tabWidget.widget(index)
        widget.deleteLater()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As you can see, it is not necessary to use the attribute Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, but if you use it, it would be enough to close the widget.

```py
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(tabsClosable=True)
        self.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.onTabCloseRequested)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabWidget)

        for i in range(10):
            widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            widget.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
            widget.destroyed.connect(
                lambda obj: print(
                    "deleted {}, count: {}".format(obj, self.tabWidget.count())
                )
            )
            self.tabWidget.addTab(widget, "Tab %s" % (i))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onTabCloseRequested(self, index):
        widget = self.tabWidget.widget(index)
        widget.close()
```

It is not necessary to use [`removeTab()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#removeTab) since this does not destroy the widget, that method is thought so that when you want to place the widget removed to another widget.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.qtabwidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self) 

        widget = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit("QPlainTextEdit 1")
        label  = 'Tab &1'
        tab_index1 = self.qtabwidget.addTab(widget, label)

        widget2 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit("QPlainTextEdit 2")        
        tab_index2 = self.qtabwidget.addTab(widget2, 'Tab &2')
        self.qtabwidget.setTabIcon(tab_index2, QtGui.QIcon('im.png'))
        self.qtabwidget.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32)) 

        self.qtabwidget.addTab(
                QtWidgets.QLabel("QLabel Tab &3", alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter), 
                QtGui.QIcon('Ok.png'),
                'Tab &3')

        self.qtabwidget.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Triangular)
        self.qtabwidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.East)          

        self.qtabwidget.setTabsClosable(True)  
        self.qtabwidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.close_handler)              
        self.qtabwidget.currentChanged.connect(self.qtabwidget_currentchanged)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.qtabwidget)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def close_handler(self, index):
        """
            Removes a tab with the specified index, but first deletes the widget it contains. 
        """

        # gets the widget
        widget = self.qtabwidget.widget(index)

        # if the widget exists
        if widget:
            # removes the widget
            widget.deleteLater()

        # removes the tab of the QTabWidget
        self.qtabwidget.removeTab(index)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def qtabwidget_currentchanged(self, index):
        print(f"The new index of the current page: {index}")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setWindowTitle('QTabWidget')
    window.resize(400, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]